# Wordpress Pull Category Id

Tags: wordpress, categories

Im trying to pull current category id when someone views a category page and included it in the shortcode to show post from the category using the plugin ... this is what I have ...

```
<?php 
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
echo do_shortcode('[ajaxgrid cats="<?php get_the_category( $cat_id ) ?>"]'); ?>
```

but its not working, it just shows all post, so I dont think that category id is being pulled properly ... anyone got any ideas ...
thank You

Answer (score 0):

cats should contain numbers like this: a,b,c,d.... I don't think it is an array, and get_the_category() is returning array.

You should create a function that returns a string like : `cat1,cat2,cat3` from an array like `{cat1,cat2,cat3}`.  Displaying categories separately with comma in between is the solution as I think.

I hope you find it.